# What are important considerations when purchasing a zoom lens?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, zoom

What should I be aware of when buying a zoom lens (other than that it will fit my camera)?  What specs should I pay close attention to?

Comment: Why the downvote?  If the question is too vague, or too subject, state it, so that the site takes shape.  Thats what this beta is for

Comment: Not a bad question ... I upvoted it for you.

Comment: Since you posted three mostly identical questions, I'll post three mostly identical comments. :) Research! See http://www.photozone.de/ for test results you can use to compare relatively similar units.

Comment: So by "research" you mean don't ask questions, look at other places on the internet. Since that answer could be applied to any question on a StackExchange site it isn't really helpful. Especially if the purpose of SE sites is to establish a reference library of answers to questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One consideration (this is a generalization, but most generalizations are based on some facts) is that usually the longer the zoom range, the quality of the image will suffer.  As an example, the mega-zooms (28-300mm for example) will usually result in softer images (especially at either end of the zoom range) than a lens with a narrower zoom range (such as 24-70mm).

In any case, look for real-world reviews and photo samples before making a purchase.

I really like the lens [review section of FredMiranda.com](http://www.fredmiranda.com/reviews/) for getting real-world reviews.

Comment: On the other hand, often ultimate quality is not needed. Get the lens that's good enough for you. No need to satisfy everyone on the internet too. :)

Comment: 15 years ago when I was reading these kind of info there was a rule of thumb that optimum ZOOMs were 1:3... And obviously still the same today.

Answer (score 6):

1. The zoom factor of course
2. Aperture, if aperture value is low you will either be able to take better photo in darkness and/or do blur effect in lower focus distance
3. Min. focus distance, you will not be able to take a correct shoot if subject is closer than this distance
4. Weight depending of your need you might not want something too heavy

Each time you want to buy a lens, try to find some review on Internet !

Comment: What about lens quality?

Answer (score 3):

If you know someone with the lens you are interested in, or a similar one, borrow and use it if you can. That goes way beyond reviews!

Comment: Or rent one you're considering buying. Try before you buy.

Comment: Haven't done that myself, but it's another useful option. It's hard to know for sure if you like a lens unless you've actually used it for a while - you don't get that in the camera store!

Answer (score -1):

I'm a big fan of Thom Hogan's lens reviews. http://bythom.com/nikon.htm

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Francesco, I'm not sure how you propose copying the bulk of Thom Hogan's site into an answer. The entire value of this answer is "here is a good resource to look at". Did you even follow the link? Please downvote thoughtfully rather than reflexively.

Comment: I didn't downvote, precisely because I know the value of the site.

Comment: @Francesco, my apologies in that case.

Comment: No problem, no harm done no offence taken :)